# Django CMS SMTP Server -- [Errno 61] Connection refused

Tags: python, django, django-cms, smtplib

I'm using Django CMS with the Aldryn Jobs module installed, by default the Jobs module uses the [emailit](https://github.com/divio/django-emailit) module, not the core mail module that comes with Django (Still not sure why).

My problem is I cannot connect to the SMTP server, whenever the app needs to send an email I'm greeted with a error page. Here is the [traceback Link](http://dpaste.com/3SKEBSJ).

As far as I know Django comes packaged with a SMTP server so this should work out the box.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django doesn't come packages with a SMTP server, so that't the reason you are getting error - it's trying to connect to non existent SMTP server.
Read more at [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/)

If you just need to try functionality in dev environment, just set dummy e-mail in your `settings.py`:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.dummy.EmailBackend'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will give the AWS SES a go and see if that works.